# How to find out what permissions users have on a particular folder?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, file-permissions, ntfs

I created this script that parses a specific directory "xyz". I have isolated "NETZ" groups that have access to this directory and run through them recursively and counted the users (unique, duplicate entries are removed). I exported the whole thing at the end with the properties **"samaccountname"** and **"name"**.

So now I have the number of users in the groups "NETZ", which have access to this directory.

```
this is a shortcut
samaccountname       Name                     
--------------       ----                     
ADM-AD-Task          ADM-AD-Task              
adm-agayk            ADM-agayk                
ADM-akorn            ADM-akorn                
ADM-algoergen        ADM-algoergen            
ADM-bklann           ADM-bklann               
ADM-chhuebner        ADM-chhuebner            
adm-ckaehler         ADM-ckaehler             
ADM-daneumann        ADM-daneumann            
ADM-dhorn            ADM-dhorn                
ADM-dkrzyzostaniak   ADM-dkrzyzostaniak       
ADM-dmetz            ADM-dmetz  

this is the output of this variable $workersunique
```

Now, in addition to "samaccountname" and "name" properties, I also want to get  the **permissions** of each user. So for example if the user has only read or also write permissions. "What permission does each user in the groups have on this directory."

Here is my script

```
#get all groups of the directory

$GroupFolder = Get-NTFSAccess -Path "\\Vh01tools\xyz"

#remove the NOT NETZ groups

$GroupFolder = $GroupFolder -match "NETZ"

#go through the groups and add the users to a variable

for ($i=0; $i -lt $GroupFolder.length; $i++){
    Write-Host $GroupFolder[$i]
    $groupsarray = $GroupFolder[$i].Account.ToString()
    $groupname = $groupsarray -replace "NETZ\\", ""
    echo $groupname
    if($groupname -eq "S-PCAdmin") {
        echo "Do not add worker"
        } else {
                echo "add worker"
                $workers += Get-ADGroupMember $groupname -Recursive | select samaccountname, Name
                
            }
}


$wn = $workers.Count
echo "There is" $wn "workers."

$workerssorted = $workers | Sort-Object -Property samaccountname, name

$workersunique = $workerssorted | Select-Object -Property samaccountname, name -Unique

$accualworkers = $workersunique.Count
echo "there is" $accualworkers " workers."

# Here i tried to get the **permissions** from each user in the groups but it didn't work. It only gets me the access rights of the mentioned Account "ajenniat" as shown in the output.

Foreach ($m in $workersunique) {
    $ma = Get-NTFSEffectiveAccess -Path "\\Vh01tools\xyz" -Account ajenniat
    $ma
    }
```

here is what i get

```
PS G:\> C:\Users\yalhares\Desktop\fg.ps1
A 'NETZ\Domain Admins' (FullControl)
Domain Admins
add worker
A 'NETZ\S-ServEDA-VIS' (ReadAndExecute, Synchronize)
S-ServEDA-VIS
add worker
A 'NETZ\S-ServEDA-DIR' (Modify, Synchronize)
S-ServEDA-DIR

# The permissions of the three groups are displayed

add worker
There is
415
workers.
there is
83
workers.
WARNUNG: The user does not hold the Security Privliege and might not be able to read the effective permissions


    Path: \\Vh01tools\xyz (Inheritance disabled)


Account                             Access Rights                                   Applies to                Type                                            IsInherited                                     InheritedFrom                                  
-------                             -------------                                   ----------                ----                                            -----------                                     -------------                                  
NETZ\ajenniat                       FullControl                                     ThisFolderOnly            Allow                                           False                                                                                          
WARNUNG: The user does not hold the Security Privliege and might not be able to read the effective permissions
NETZ\ajenniat                       FullControl                                     ThisFolderOnly            Allow                                           False
```

As you can see, i can only get the access right from the specified username "ajenniat". i still need to get the permissions for the rest of the 82 users.

I seriously so badly want to get this working. any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: In your loop, one of your arguments is `-Account ajenniat`. What happens when you try `-Account * ` ?

Comment: Hey @Steezy, Thanks for your quick reply. I tried that but it did not work.

that returns:  Get-NTFSEffectiveAccess : The parameter "Account" cannot be bound. The value "*" cannot be converted to the type "Security2.IdentityReference2". Error: "Some or all identity references could not be translated."

Comment: Hmm okay. I'll have to look into it more. As a temp alternative could you use ICACLS to view permissions. Ex: `icacls "C:\PutYourPathHere"`

Comment: @Steezy OK, i get this : PS G:\> icacls "\\Vh01tools\xyz"
\\Vh01tools\xyz NETZ\Domain Admins:(OI)(CI)(F)
                BUILTIN\Administratoren:(OI)(CI)(F)
                NETZ\S-ServEDA-DIR:(OI)(CI)(M)
                NETZ\S-ServEDA-VIS:(OI)(CI)(RX)

Comment: Those are the inheritance rights granted. See [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls).

Comment: @Steezy it's not working. I have also tried to pipeline it but i still only get "name" and "samaccountname".  `$MAsortedandunique = $mitabeidersorted | Select-Object -Property samaccountname, Name -Unique | Get-NTFSEffectiveAccess -Account $mitabeider | select Account, AccessControlType, AccessRights, FullName`. But it gives me this: PS G:\> $MAsortedandunique

samaccountname       Name                     
---------       ----                     
ADM-AD-Task          ADM-AD-Task              
adm-agayk            ADM-agayk                
ADM-akorn            ADM-akorn